# How much information do I gain from each modular inequality?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, recurrence-relations

**Problem details**:

Let $p = 2^{48}$, $s\leftarrow\{0,1\}^{48}$, and $a,b$ known constants.

Furthermore let $f(x) = a x + b \pmod{p}$

and let the value $r_k$  be defined by the first-order recurrence relation:

$r_0 = s$

$r_i = f(f(r_{i-1}))$.

Suppose we are given a sequence of values $V = [c(r_1), c(r_2), ... , c(r_n)]$

where we can think of $c(x)$ as a bit mask that reveals only the 6 most significant bits of some bit string $x$.

**Question:**

How long does $V$ need to be in order to solve for $s$?

**Background:**

Some implementations of Javascript use a Linear Congruential Generator (LCG) for the `Math.random()` built-in function. I'd like to see if, given a masked sequence of outputs from `Math.random()`, I can infer the internal state of the LCG, and thus be able to predict future masked values. If so, how many values do I need to do this?

**My educated guess/approach:**

I've been racking my brain/whiteboard about this problem all weekend, but I feel uncomfortable trying to reason about modular arithmetic.

I would think that with each $r_i$ we gain at least a little information about the internal state. Since we need to learn about a 48-bit number, and we learn only 6 bits per $r_i$, we probably need at least *8 values* ($6*8 = 48$) before it's possible to completely infer $s$. In my specific case I get an average of 30 consecutive values, which I would think would be plenty.

One promising idea that I had last night was to think of each $c(r_i)$ as denoting an inequality over the range of possible $r_i$ values, and then solve for some system of modular inequalities-- which I have no idea how to do.

Comment: Also, is this the right board for this question?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details of the algorithm, but you might want to look up Håstad and Shamir's paper "The Cryptographic Security of Truncated Linearly related Variables".  It looks like this paper and the related "Reconstructing Truncated Integer Variables..." are available on [Håstad's web page](http://www.nada.kth.se/~johanh/papers.html).

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks, I actually appreciate the references more than an answer =)

Comment: Do you really mean $f(f(r_{i-1}))$, not $f(r_{i-1})$? Running $f$ twice at each iteration is the same as running some other linear function $g$ once, anyway.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: According to [this article](http://landing2.trusteer.com/sites/default/files/Temporary_User_Tracking_in_Major_Browsers.pdf) the generator is advanced twice per value generated; but I do see your point, perhaps that will help simplify my deduction process later. Thanks!